# binary search in c++ using 2d array

Tags: c++, xcode, function, binary-search

Write a loop to ask the user for a gpa and check that it's not negative before doing the search end the loop when the user enters a negative value. When there is a match, print the corresponding student number; when there is no match, print "No match".

I am working on the binary search function. I want to code to check and stop if a negative number is entered and print the student nummber (or "Not found") when a gpa is entered.

```
void search (double AVGgpa[][NUM_STUDENTS])
{
    double gpa;

    int first = 0,                  
    last = NUM_STUDENTS - 1,
    mid,
    position = -1;
    int row = 2;
    bool found = false;         // not found yet

    cout << "Enter gpa(-1 to end): ";
    cin >> gpa;
    if (gpa==-1)
    {
        cout<<"You enter a nagative value"<<endl;
    }

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;     
        if (AVGgpa[row][mid]== gpa)  
        {
            cout << "found at index " << mid << endl;
            found = true;
        }
        else if (AVGgpa[row][mid]> gpa)
            last = mid - 1;        
        else   
            first = mid + 1;          
    }
```

Comment: What's your issue?  What exact problem are you having, what don't you understand about how to fix it, what have you tried and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: i am trying to print out the students number When i enter their gpa. i tried to do it but i everytime it says not found no matter what

Comment: Have you tried putting a line of trace in so you can see what is happening?  E.g. `std::cout << "mid [" << mid << "] " << AVGgpa[row][mid] << '\n';` just after `mid = ...;`  That should give you a lot more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is correct and the array sorted by `row`, you are probably running into trouble because of float-inacurracy.

Look at the following questions for details: [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

From that you can use a comparision function like:

```
bool doubleCompare(double d1, double d2)
{
  static const double epsilon = 0.001;  // Define this as needed
  return std::fabs(d1 - d2) < epsilon;
}
```

If that does **not** help you, you should check your input data and/or post more code, since your binary search looks ok to me.